# $display in Verilog and printf in C

Tags: c, verilog

As you know in `Verilog` has `$display,$strobe` and $monitor  those used to display text on the screen.
And in C has `printf` to display text on screen also.

My question is how can I use one of them (`$display,$strobe,$monitor`) like `printf` in `C`?

```
a: $display
b:$strobe
c:$monitor
d: all of them
e: other
```

Comment: $display("Put your text here or you can do this %s, %d" string,value);

Answer (score 32):

```
$display("<format>", exp1, exp2, ...);  // formatted write to display
format indication %b %B binary
                  %c %C character (low 8 bits)
                  %d %D decimal  %0d for minimum width field
                  %e %E E format floating point %15.7E
                  %f %F F format floating point %9.7F
                  %g %G G general format floating point
                  %h %H hexadecimal
                  %l %L library binding information
                  %m %M hierarchical name, no expression
                  %o %O octal
                  %s %S string, 8 bits per character, 2´h00 does not print
                  %t %T simulation time, expression is  $time
                  %u %U unformatted two value data  0 and 1 
                  %v %V net signal strength
                %z %Z unformatted four value data  0, 1, x, z

escape sequences, quoted characters in strings \n   newline
                                               \t   tab
                                               \\   backslash
                                               \"   quote
                                               \ddd octal
                                               %%   percent

any other characters between the quotes are displayed
the expressions are taken in order of the format indication
,, in the expression list inserts one space in the output
```

Comment: Thanks, `%d` appears to be quite ugly because it inserts unasked for padding, `%0d` was just what I needed.